# Access localhost on BlackBerry simulator

Tags: php, blackberry

I can't access localhost with my BlackBerry simulator.  How do I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using your machine's own IP instead of localhost?

Comment: do i need to do this, there is a tutorial i saw that actually used http://127.0.0.1 and everything worked well. So why is this different.

Comment: There might be another issue affecting it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427582/how-to-access-localhost-websites-through-http-request-from-blackberry-simulator

Answer (score 0):

check ip and then copy and past it to your mobile. example: your_ip/your_progect/index.html

ubuntu users: check 
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145012/how-can-i-find-my-public-ip-using-the-terminal)

windows users: check
[here](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/workingwithipaddresses/a/ipconfig.htm)